# validate input only if the input box is not empty

Tags: php, jquery, joomla2.5

i have a file input box which is not required for validation. But if the input box is not empty then i want the validation for file type and file size to be executed.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.validator.addMethod("accept", function(value, element, param) {
    return value.match(new RegExp("." + param + "$"));
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param) 
});


jQuery('#adminform').validate({

    rules: {

        resume: {
                required: false,
                accept: "(doc|docx|pdf)",
                filesize: 1024 //1048576
        }
    },
......................
    resume: {
        accept: "File type not supported",
        filesize: "File cannot be more than 1MB!"
    },
```

For now the problem is that even if i don't supply any input and leave it empty, i get the rule **"accept"** executed i.e i get the message **"File type not supported"**.

Comment: the thing here is that i don't want to make the field compulsory, i want to validate the input only if the users upload a file

Comment: Use on change event for that input file field.

Comment: `$("input[type=file]").on("change", function() { $(this).validate({ }); });`

Comment: i apologize but i just want to know where i have to put this line in my case, i am quite new to jquery and i understand the validation plugin a bit

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Not empty check ensures that if field is left blank then validation won't be performed

```
$('input[type="file"]').on("change", function() { 
if ($this.val() !== '') { 
    //do validation stuff here!!
} 
});
```

Comment: `if ($this.val() !== '') { }` what's this? if the input has changed, it will definitely have a value :)

Answer (score 0):

Tryout this if this helps:

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
rules: {
    name: "required",
    file: "required",
    name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
    },
    file: {
        required: false,
        minlength: 5
    }
},
messages: {
    name: {
        required: "Please enter a username",
        minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
    },
    file: {
        required: "Please select a file",
        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
    }
},
submitHandler: function(form) {
    if ($('#cfile').val() != "") {
        $("#commentForm").validate({
            rules: {
                file: "required",
                file: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                }
            },
            messages: {
                file: {
                    required: "Please select a file"
                }
            }
        });
        $(form).submit();
    } else {
        alert('file missing.');
    }
}

});
```

Comment: i used your handler method but the error is gone but i do not get the validation executed, i mean the rules accept and filesize do not get executed.

Comment: have you tried placing that just inside of `if ($('#cfile').val() != "") { `